# FTDI. Setting device description using FT_EE_Program doesn work

Tags: c, hardware

I want to change device description in a FTDI-Chip.
For that, I define first FT_PROGRAM_DATA ftData, call FT_EE_Read, modify the field ftData.Description and finally call FT_EE_Program for writing the data back. The code example is:

```
FT_PROGRAM_DATA ftData;
FT_STATUS ftStatus = FT_EE_Read(ftHandle, &ftData); 
strcpy( ftData.Description, "My New Description" );
ftStatus = FT_EE_Program (ftHandle, &ftData );
```

The results (ftStatus) of both FT- functions are FT_OK.
However, when I call FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail, the description returned is old one.
Doesn't FT_EE_Program and FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail use the same device description?
Thank you very much for any hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it. The description seems not to be updated on EE_Program. After re-connection of USB-Cable the desciption changes. There is a function:

```
FT_CyclePort(ftHandle);
```

which simulates re-connection programmatically.

Comment: Just to confirm your finding every time I update the EEPROM of a FT232RL or FT231X for a Nusbio device,  I unplug and re-plug the device.